# I am looking for the correct translation of love for the phrase "in this sign love"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you say "In this sign love" as in the similar style saying of "In hoc signo vinces"?

Answer (score 7):

The phrase *in hōc signō vincēs*, as in the words Constantine saw, uses a future indicative form: it's not an order to conquer, it's a statement of pure fact. "In this sign *you will conquer*." The word you'd want to change is *vincēs*.

If you want to keep that same grammatical form, "you will love" as a statement of fact, that would be *amābis* in the singular (like *vincēs*), but *amābitis* in the plural.

If you want it to be a command ("love!"), that would be *amā* singular, *amāte* plural (the present imperative). And if you want it to be a suggestion or a wish, "may you love", that would be *amēs*/*amētis*, the present (=future-ish) subjunctive in 2nd person singular/plural.

Comment: In hoc signo amor [est] could also be an alternative! Just in case the OP wants to stick to that meaning